# Build request with IP address

Tags: haskell, request, ip, http-conduit

I would like to know how to build a request with server's IP address (not URL).

Actually I start with a given URL and then with the help of lenses rebuild the request:

```
   connect = do
        request' <- parseRequest "http://localhost"
        let request = setRequestMethod "POST"
                    $ setRequestHost (S8.pack ("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"))
                    $ ...
```

It works fine but it's inelegant, clumsy code.

Comment: What's wrong with `"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`?

Comment: Nthg. It just a placeholder

Comment: No, what's wrong with just passing your IP address into `parseRequest` instead of `localhost`, like `"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`? The `http://` should make it a valid URL.

Comment: You're right parsing with "http:// xx.xxx.xxx.xx" do the job, I was sure that I checked this without success but now it's working (strange, I messed surely something else at the time..)

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less what you're supposed to do when you create a `Request` from scratch, except there's a predefined `defaultRequest` equivalent to `http://localhost`.  So, use:

```
request = setRequestMethod "POST"
        $ setRequestHost (S8.pack "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
        $ ... 
        $ defaultRequest
```

and I think you're doing it right.